# How to use delete with a variable pointed to by two pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

As it says here: [How to use delete with a variable pointed to by two pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392546/how-to-use-delete-with-a-variable-pointed-to-by-two-pointers)
one can only delete once, then all pointers won't work, but the code below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string * str1 = new string("abc");
    string * str2 = str1;
    cout<< *str2 <<endl;
    delete str1;
    str1 = NULL;
    cout<< *str2<<endl;
}
```

the output is:

```
abc
abc
```

so, what's the matter?

Comment: Undefined Behavior, that's what

Comment: welcome to the magical world of undefined behavior

Comment: You're dereferencing a pointer pointing to deleted memory, that's undefined behaviour (i.e., anything can happen).

Comment: That you "cannot use" the pointers means that you're not allowed to, not that it isn't possible or that anything in particular will happen if you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have deleted a pointer, accessing it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and may print old contents sometimes, may crash sometimes or may do something beyond thinking some other time.

To handle a case of deleting shared pointer, use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or similar reference counting manager wrapper instead of naked pointers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the outcomes of *undefined behavior* is that is might seem to work. And dereferencing a pointer to a destructed object (like you do with `cout<< *str2<<endl;`) is undefined behavior.